# Populating NSDictionary and NSArrays for Model data

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdictionary, xcode4.3

I'm trying to create an `NSDictionary` full of arrays in the implementation file of my model but my code hasn't worked yet. I want to create arrays that are lists of types of dogs and cats and then add those arrays to a dictionary with keys called `DOG` and `CAT`. Here is my code:

```
@implementation wordDictionary

@synthesize catList = _catList;
@synthesize dogList = _dogList;
@synthesize standardDictionary =_standardDictionary;
- (void)setCatList:(NSMutableArray *)catList
{
     self.catList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"lion", @"puma", @"snow leopard", nil]; 
}
- (void)setDogList:(NSMutableArray *)dogList
{
    self.dogList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"pit bull", @"pug", @"chihuahua", nil];
}
-(void)setStandardDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)standardDictionary 
{
    [self.standardDictionary setObject: _catList forKey:@"CAT"];
    [self.standardDictionary setObject: _dogList forKey:@"DOG"];
}

- (NSString*)selectKey    
{
    NSInteger keyCount = [[self.standardDictionary allKeys] count];
    NSInteger randomKeyIndex = arc4random() % keyCount;
    NSString *randomKey = [[self.standardDictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex:randomKeyIndex];
    return randomKey;
}
@end
```

This code is the model. The model is hooked up to my view controller such that when a user taps a button, the `NSString` returned from `randomKey` is displayed in a label on the screen. So the text will read either `CAT` or `DOG`. Here's the code for that:

```
- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(UIButton*)sender {
    NSString *chosenKey = [self.dictionary selectKey];
    NSString *labelText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", chosenKey];
    self.label.text = labelText;
}
```

Unfortunately when I tap the button on the simulator I get an error message saying: `Thread 1:EXC_ARITHMETIC (code=EXC_1386_DIV, subcode=0x0)` at `NSInteger randomKeyIndex = arc4random() % keyCount;` and it appears that I'm getting it because neither my `NSArray` nor my `NSDictionary` have any objects inside of them.

Does anyone have any idea why my `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` haven't been populated?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you called `setCatList:`, `setDogList:` and `setStandardDictionary:` before. Probably that causing is this :

```
 NSString *chosenKey = [self.dictionary selectKey];
```

change into this :

```
 NSString *chosenKey = [self selectKey];
```

**UPDATE**

I'm trying to make your life easier. no need to create your object if you don't need the most.

```
- (NSMutableArray*)getCatList
{
     return [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"lion", @"puma", @"snow leopard", nil]; 
}
- (NSMutableArray*)getDogList
{
   return [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"pit bull", @"pug", @"chihuahua", nil];
}
-(NSMutableDictionary*)getStandardDictionary 
{
    NSMutableDictionary *standardDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [standardDictionary setObject:[self getCatList] forKey:@"CAT"];
    [standardDictionary setObject:[self getDogList] forKey:@"DOG"];
    return [standardDictionary autorelease];
}

- (NSString*)selectKey    
{
    NSMutableDictionary *standardDictionary = [self getStandardDictionary];
    NSInteger keyCount = [[standardDictionary allKeys] count];
    NSInteger randomKeyIndex = arc4random() % keyCount;
    NSString *randomKey = [[standardDictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex:randomKeyIndex];
    return randomKey;
}

- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(UIButton*)sender {
   // NSString *chosenKey = [self selectKey];
    //NSString *labelText = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", chosenKey];
    self.label.text = [self selectKey]; //no need to convert it to NSString again
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that there isn't any code here that calls the methods to set the arrays or dictionary.

But the real underlying issue is that there are a couple of bad 'patterns' going on here that you should fix:

In your setter methods (setCatList:, setDogList:, setStandardDictionary:) you're not setting the properties in question to the values that are passed in.  For example, you should be setting catList to the passed in "catList" variable.

```
- (void)setCatList:(NSMutableArray *)catList
{
    if (_catList != catList) {
      [_catList release];
      _catList = [catList retain];
    }
}
```

Then you should have some kind of "setup" happening, usually in a method in the view controller like viewDidLoad:

```
[wordDictionary setCatList:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"lion", @"puma", @"snow leopard", nil]]; 
// and more for the other two setters
```

Alternately, you can set these default values in the init for the wordDictionary class:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setCatList:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"lion", @"puma", @"snow leopard", nil]]; 
    }
    return self;
}
```

The former is better in most cases, but you may have a good reason to pre-populate your model for all instances of the class.

Comment: So is there no way to keep the model data and controller separate in this case? I was thinking that I shouldn't put the lists in the view controller to stick with MVC design. Is that unnecessary? Thanks for responding.

Comment: You can provide an initializer for this model class that would set these values.  I'll append my answer with that example as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm new to this so the help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: One other thing -- if the list doesn't change -- ie it's set to these values for all cases, you generally want that to be a NSArray, not an NSMutableArray.  Get used to using NSArray for arrays that don't change. It will make your code safer.

Comment: A million thanks for the tips! I appreciate you taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to consider:

I don't see you calling these:

```
setCatList:(NSMutableArray*)catList;
setDogList:(NSMutableArray*)dogList;
```

You use self.catList and self.dogList, but neither of those are synthesized, instead you have beatList and meList synthesized

Change the synthesizes to the catList and dogList, and make sure you call the set list methods, and then you should make some progress.